# Python "while x:" statement

Tags: python, while-loop

Why the following while loop is exited when `x` reaches `0`?

```
x = 1
while x:
    print(x)
    x -= 1
```

It prints only `1`. Shouldn't the while statement be something like: `while x "is something":` and not just `while x:`?

Comment: Because the integer object `0` evaluates to `False` in a boolean context: `bool(0) == False`. All objects in Python are either "truthy" or "falsy".

Comment: Also, [_What is Truthy and Falsy in python? How is it different from True and False?_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-in-python-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false) would be useful as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `bool(0) => False`, and `bool(x) for x!=0 => True`, so it's like saying `while x!=0` or `while x>0` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

In boolean, none zero value means 'true' and 0 means 'false'. The code reaches the argument while(0) or while(false) and terminate the body