# Please explain why programm would go into the if statement

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, while-loop

Below is a simple python code, which just prints the actual time/date with delay. I would be very grateful if someone can explain to me (as simply as possible) when and why the programm goes into the if statement (if exitFlag:) What is the statement? if exitFLag == True? Sry I don't understand this line.

I tried to copy the function with a similiar and simpler code. But here the programm won't go into the if statement. I hope someone can help me to understand the code better.

```py
test = 0
counter = 10
while counter:
    if test:
        print("if-statement is called")
        break
    print("still in loop")
    counter -=1
```

```py
import threading
import time


exitFlag = 0

class myThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name, counter):        
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)                 
        self.threadID = threadID                        
        self.name = name
        self.counter = counter

    def run(self):                                      
        print("Starting " + self.name)
        print_time(self.name, self.counter, 5)          
        print("Exiting " + self.name)


def print_time(threadName, counter, delay):
    while counter:
        if exitFlag:                                   
            threadName.exit()
        time.sleep(delay)
        print("%s: %s" % (threadName, time.ctime(time.time())))
        counter -= 1


thread1 = myThread(1, "Thread-1", 1)
thread2 = myThread(2, "Thread-2", 2)

thread1.start()
thread2.start()
thread1.join()
thread2.join()

print("Exiting main thread")
```

Comment: [Python `while x:` statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46045023/python-while-x-statement) is another effective duplicate, as is [Python evaluates 0 as false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497199/python-evaluates-0-as-false).

Comment: ...either way, none of the code here will ever enter the `if exitFlag:` or `if test:` sections, because nothing in either section ever assigns truthy values to the tested variables.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So in Truth Value Testing (when you check if something is true or false), you can use a lot of different values.

[Python's Docs](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/truth.html) say you can use the following values to represent false:

> - `None`
> - `False`
> - zero of any numeric type, for example, `0, 0L, 0.0, 0j`.
> - any empty sequence, for example, '', (), [].
> - any empty mapping, for example, {}.
> - instances of user-defined classes, if the class defines a `__nonzero__()` or `__len__()` method, when that method returns the integer zero or bool value False.

Anything else evaluates to true.

In this program, `exitFlag` is an integer. The code

```
if exitFlag:                                   
        threadName.exit()
```

is basically saying: "If exitFlag is **not** 0, exit the thread"

That being said, the code never seems to change `exitFlag` from `0`, so this if statement will likely never be entered